# Unbuntu 22.04 (Jammy) slow

Tags: 22.04

I have an Intel K7700 cpu (8 core) with 72GB of Ram, 3 SSD's, and two mechanical.  My system is slow and unresponsive at times for no apparent good reason.  For example, if I attempt to open a simple jpg file (30kb!) with Image viewer it just spins with the wheel like it's doing something and then just disappears and never opens the program.  I could have to try clicking on it 4 times before it finally does it. So annoying! I run video through an RTX 2070.  SSD's are capable of over 2000mb/sec.  I just don't understand what the problem is.  Swap space is 2gb I believe but with 72gb of ram I would think I could even turn off swap...  Any ideas??? Also I have the same issue with the default file explorer and tried Dolphin as well to see if that would solve it, but it didn't.

Comment: Check journalctl for errors. And install the native NVIDIA drivers for your card. They should run within the XServer environment, not Wayland.